# making a simple ball class for moving ball but not moving

Tags: java, class, oop

i'm making a simple program for moving ball, but unfortunately it's not moving, when i put values x=5, and y=4 after running program it's showing "Ball @ (0.0,0.0)" on console please help where is my mistake.

```
public class Ball
{
    private double x,y; //private variables...

//creating constructors..
public void Ball(double x, double y)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
public void Ball()
{
    x=5.0;
    y=4.0;
}
//getter and setter for private variables....
public double getX()
{
    return x;
}
public void setX()
{
    this.x=x;
}
public double getY()
{
    return y;
}
public void setY()
{
    this.y=y;
}
public void setXY(double x, double y)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
public void move(double Xdisp, double Ydisp)
{
    x+=Xdisp;
    y+=Xdisp;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Ball @ ("+x+","+y+")";
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Ball b=new Ball();
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), thus the default one is called, which does nothing to `x` and `y`.

In order to have what you intended to, you should provide a constructor (You're almost there), just remove `void` modifier:

**public <strike>void</strike> Ball()**

Now, this is a constructor. Note that you should do the same for the other meant-to-be-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `void` keyword from the constructor of `Ball` to allow `x` and `y` to be assigned values

```
public Ball() {
    x = 5.0;
    y = 4.0;
}
```

Comment: Constructors do not have a return type, what you have is a method which doesnt get called

Answer (score 0):

`public void Ball()` Must be a constructor.

```
public Ball()
{
    x=5.0;
    y=4.0;
}
```

But you've written as a method. Also there is no parameter in set method, must be like

```
public void setX(double x)
{
    this.x=x;
}
public void setY(double y)
{
    this.y=y;
}
```